# Corrupt usr/bin/java

Tags: java, jar

I just did a pretty stupid thing, when I tried to copy JSTestDriver.jar into usr/bin/java by typing this command: cp jsTestDriver.jar usr/bin/java.

Now every 'java' command in terminal just prints out this:

```
/usr/bin/java: line 1: PK: command not found
/usr/bin/java: line 2:Q?EA: command not found
/usr/bin/java: line 3P?EAan???META-INF/MANIFEST.MFM???: No such file or directory
~?n?/bin?m8?|<(.???l?s?.???c}?s??N̥7?)??U[?/????PB?PK
Tg.Acom/PK
Tg.A
    com/google/PK
Vg.Acom/google/jstestdriver/PK
Tg.Acom/google/jstestdriver/action/PK
Tg.A$com/google/jstestdriver/annotations/PK
Tg.A com/google/jstestdriver/browser/PK
Tg.A!com/google/jstestdriver/commands/PK
Tg.Acom/google/jstestdriver/config/PK
Ug.A!com/google/jstestdriver/debugger/PK
Ug.A!com/google/jstestdriver/embedded/PK
Ug.Acom/google/jstestdriver/guice/PK
Ug.Acom/google/jstestdriver/hooks/PK
Vg.Acom/google/jstestdriver/html/PK
P?EA#com/google/jstestdriver/javascript/PK
Vg.A*com/google/jstestdriver/javascript/compat/PK
P?EAcom/google/jstestdriver/javascript/lib/PK: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/java: line 20:Vg.A+com/google/jstestdriver/javascript/plugins/PK: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/java: line 21:Vg.A1com/google/jstestdriver/javascript/plugins/async/PK: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/java: line 22:Ug.Acom/google/jstestdriver/model/PK: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/java: line 23:Ug.Acom/google/jstestdriver/output/PK: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/java: line 24:Ug.A: command not found
/usr/bin/java: line 25:Ug.A!com/google/jstestdriver/protocol/PK: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/java: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `com/google/jstestdriver/requesthandlers/PK'
/usr/bin/java: line 26: Ug.A(com/google/jstestdriver/requesthandlers/PK'
```

I've googled my problem, but cannot find a solution to my problem.

I am running Mac OS 10.6.8, which doesn't support Java SE 7.0. Which i had hoped would fix my problem.

Does anyone know how I can restore /usr/bin/java ?

Comment: which java version do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/java` is usually just a symlink, sometimes to your actual java installation, sometimes to something like `/etc/alternatives/java`.

What java are you using?  Sun/Oracle?  OpenJDK?  And what is your distro?

Running the command:

```
find / -type f -name java
```

Should get you started finding the real java binary.

Comment: That makes sense. I found the real binary in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands

As far as I can remember I have (or had) java -verson 1.6.0.(something) installed.

How can I link /usr/bin/java to the actual java installation again? And how can I move JsTestDriver.jar to the correct folder? I beleive I have seen people just copying jar files into /usr/bin/java or something...

Comment: Just in case : on my machine, /usr/bin/java points to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java

Comment: `cd /usr/bin; rm java; ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java .`

Comment: I've now removed the old java symlink in /usr/bin and replaced it with a new link from the actual java installation, as user829775 suggested. Still doesn't work - same error as I got earlier.

Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: What does `ls  -l /usr/bin/java` show?

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Jun 19 23:35 java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run: `cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/; ./java` ?

Comment: Or lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 74 Jun 19 23:35 java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java, I've tried both Versions/A/... and Versions/Current. Still the same error

Comment: @jedwards: yes, same error. that means trouble right?

Comment: Yep, it means you trampled the actual binary.  I'm not familiar with Java on MacOS, but re-installing / uninstalling and installing should fix it.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll probably get rid of this old OSX update anyways and install a linux distro. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

just to be sure: could you execute the following and post the result?

```
readlink -f /usr/bin/java
file /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java -version
```

Comment: the first command: readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]

Comment: the second command: pretty much the same error as above.